# how bad could be duplicate tables or left null fields when designing a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently designing a DB for a website, its quite simple, but I will have many entries of information and I dont want to leave a weak design. So , basically, I found a problem in create two tables with same structure or create just one but at other leave some text fields as null.

I have a table `area` , but I need also to create other named `sub-area` , both will have their own set of `images`, but some data only from area and subarea will be shared, and subarea might have many long text information that area wont have, text fields.

So, basically, what I did was, create a table named `area` and created a boolean field that will tell me if is sub-area or not, also a foreign key to itself that can be null but will be used to point the parent area in case the area its a subarea, and at the images table create a foreign key to area (because both area and subarea can have many images).

My problem is now, I have an area-information table (because its gonna have quite many fields that I wont use, so i dont really want to load it for nothing) , that table has a one-one relation to area table, but some fields of that area-information are specific of sub-area only, due I dont have a sub-area only table, I thought about leave them as `NULL` at the schema, fields are `TEXT` and i dont know if this is a big mistake or is an accurate decision, taking in consideration I want not to overload the server with queries (due the info will be plenty enough, so traffic will)

Any idea? Thanks.[image]

Comment: I can see several flavours for something of this nature, which one is 'best' is hard to say. My tip is normalise first and then assess the impact. Denormalising is easy, Renormalising when you decide storage. data integrity has a higher value is way painful. I'd consider denormalising before you've started , premature.

Comment: could you give me an example of how would you make the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of several ways you could start to approach this. Note despite people running around talking about Sixth Normal form, practical database design is as much art as science.

Based on what I could glean from your question

```
InfoGroups InfoGroupID (PK)
           InfoType, (Unique Key with InfoGroupID ?)
           Info

Areas    AreaID (PK), 
         any other attributes soley down to area,
         InfoGroupID (FK to InfoGroups)

SubAreas SubAreaID (PK)
         any other attributes soley down to sub area,
         AreaID (FK to Areas),
         InfoGroupID (FK to InfoGroups)
```

You could go further if Info's are common to areas/subareas and Make InfoGroups a many to many and have an Info Table...
Whether Info Type is a magic number, and enum, a string or an FK to an InfoTypes table is another set of options.

If the only difference between Areas and SubAreas was the link, you go for a self referential table, though I personally wouldn't unless subAreas had further subAreas..

Not seeing this being too expensive off the bat, but I don't know your needs. Data wise it's simplish, neat and efficient and it's way better than a shed load of ambiguous null columns.

Comment: hi, thank for the answer, could you take a look on my diagram?

Comment: No idea where you got the right hand side of it from based in what you originally posted. Don't like your version of sub-are at all, as soon as I see column1, column2, columnN etc, I get the heebies. Left side looks a good start though. The right answer is the one that works for you, no way I can do more than hint from here and then only based on my interpretation of what I think you've told me.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the help, actually, the right version of the DB is based ont he first one, and that was my question, if I should use more tables or not, I dont know if is good idea to let the area and subarea at one same table and set the specific subarea fields as null, what is heavier for the database engine?

Comment: Shouldn't matter all that much performance wise. The confusion is more down to recusive queries on the self referential table and having sub-are columns that look like they might be part of area as well.